# Binding chain with slider and text box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I would like to binding as below:

A (in View) <---> B (in View) <----> C (MyData)

Binding A-B : Two way

Binding B-C : One way

Xaml

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=textBox, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Path=MyValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Click="button_Click"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
public int MyValue
{
    get { return m_value; }
    set
    {
        m_value = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyValue");
    }
}
...
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyValue = 10;
}
```

I expect that when I click on button, the value of text box and slider bar will be updated.
However, nothing happen.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank in advance.

Comment: you shouldn't be binding views to views you should bind A=>C B=>C

Comment: If you use WPF, you should use the MVVM pattern instead of CodeBehind, which is based on a ViewModel, you work on commands instead of events.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is wrong in the architecture, that's why i would suggest you to take a look at some documentation about MVVM

such as:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level

or instead of considering just PRISM there are some more that are powerful but more approchable and easier such as MvvmLight:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1037/mvvm-light-wpf-model-view-viewmodel

Hope having been useful

Comment: Actually, I have been using MVVM to my project, I only described my problem briefly.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was not easy to figure out.
Why don't you post your (real) case? or your problem based on the mvvm framework you would like to use?

Comment: Now, i'm quite busy to post fully my case, I will update my question later, I'm sorry.